# Formas de pegar somente o mês das datas registradas no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso pegar somente os meses das datas de um determinado campo que está em meu banco de dados, porém, de preferência sem ser utilizando `SELECT MONTH`.

Dessa forma, conseguimos pegar o mês atual da data de hoje:

```
$mes_atual = date('m'); 
echo $mes_atual; //Seria exibido "06" - hoje é dia 22/06/2020
```

Estava querendo algo parecido, mas com as datas do banco, vou deixar um exemplo que eu sei que não faz muito sentido, mas só para vocês compreenderem melhor.

### **Meu código de exemplo:**

```
   $sql = "SELECT prazo FROM comercio";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

   while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  
   $mes_atual = date('m')$row['prazo'];  //Aqui pegaria somente o mês das datas vindas do banco

   }
```

É possível eu resgatar esses meses do *banco de dados* de outra forma? sem ser usando o `SELECT MONTH`, se *NÃO*, por que?

Comment: Ou você recupera a data completa de seu SGBD e extrai o mês em sua aplicação ou recupera apenas o mês, utilizando a função `month`, de seu SGBD e entrega apenas o mês para sua aplicação. Não consegui entender sua pergunta final. Obviamente quanto menos dados você trafegar na rede mais eficiente será sua aplicação.

Comment: @anonimo em meu post, basicamente estou perguntando se existem outras maneiras de resgatar somente o **mês** de uma data que está no banco de dados (MySQL), sem ser usando o `SELECT MONTH`

Comment: Qual o problema com o "month" ?

Comment: SELECT prazo FROM comercio where month(now()) = month(prazo) , seria isto ?

Comment: Não, é exibido o mês atual e depois a data do banco... Esse código de exemplo é para dizer que eu quero pegar somente o mês dessa data do banco. Eu estou conseguindo resolver o problema e irei postar a resposta aqui, mas não tive para aonde fugir...

Comment: Explica mas não complica. Primeiro vc diz //Seria exibido "06" - hoje é dia 22/06/2020 -- depois vc diz //Aqui pegaria somente o mês das datas vindas do banco. Então, é do dia de hoje ou de todas as datas?

Comment: Entendi patavina.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo de todas as datas que possuem no campo do banco, desculpe se não fui claro, mas o POST foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = ("SELECT prazo FROM comercio");

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    
        //retorna um novo objeto DateTime.
        $date = date_create($row['prazo']);
        
        //retorna uma data formatada de acordo com o formato especificado
        $mes_atual =  date_format($date, 'm');
        $data = date_format($date, 'd/m/Y');
        echo $mes_atual." -  Prazo ". $data;
        echo "<br>\n";
        
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: Muito bem, eu fiz de outra forma, mas o seu também funcionou. Vou estar respondendo com a minha resposta, mas irei deixar a sua como solução, grato.

Answer (score 0):

Use a função date_format

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

```
select date_format(now(),'%m')
```

Comment: Não sei se isso me ajuda...

Comment: Mas isso é outra forma de retornar o mês, não seria isso? Qual sua dificuldade?

Comment: Não seria isso, a sua resposta retorna o mês atual em `SQL`, precisaria de formas para retornar os meses de datas do banco no `PHP`... Tentei utilizar esse exemplo no `PHP` também (para datas do banco), mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Só voce alterar onde está now() e colocar o campo que você quer que retorna o mês. SELECT date_format(prazo,'%m') FROM comercio

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar Rodrigo!

Answer (score 0):

Não tive para aonde fugir, e acabei usando o `SELECT MONTH`, eu não sabia que eu podia selecionar um campo *duas vezes* em um só `SELECT`, segue a minha resposta abaixo que funcionou:

```
$sql = "SELECT comercio.*, date_format(comercio.prazo,'%m') as mes_prazo, tabela1.nome, tabela2.preco
FROM comercio, tabela1, tabela2
WHERE comercio.nome = tabela1.nome";

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

echo $cont['mes_prazo']; //Aqui exibe todos os meses registrados no banco, que eu precisava usar fazer uma condição. Além desses meses são exibidos as datas completas...

}
```

Comment: Hahaha, ai você ta indo contra a sua pergunta  "e preferência sem ser utilizando SELECT MONTH". Mas tá valendo, o importante é você ficar feliz!!! +1

Comment: Sim kkkkkkk, por que eu iria ter que trabalhar com `2 while` e não gostaria, mas o importante é que funcionou!